# Adapting openssl_encrypt function from PHP into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, kettle, pyopenssl

I'm trying to adapt the PHP function `openssl_encrypt` into MySQL in order to be able to do the same via kettle.

With **PHP** I do:

```
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt(trim('palima'), 'AES-256-CBC', hash('sha256', 'e99
008846853ff3b725c27315e469fbc'), 0, substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret iv'
), 0, 16)));
```

Where:

- 'palima' is the key I'm trying to encrypt.
- 'AES-256-CBC' is the cipher method.
- hash('sha256', 'e99008846853ff3b725c27315e469fbc') is my password.
- 0 is the option I've chosen.
- substr(hash('sha256', 'This is my secret iv'), 0, 16))) is the IV.

**MySQL**

```
set block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
select TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(TRIM('palima'),sha2('e99008846853ff3b725c27315e469f
bc',256),substring(sha2('This is my secret iv',256),1,16)));
```

The mid results I get are:

- select SHA2('e99008846853ff3b725c27315e469fbc',256):

78f9f18e2bd0e8c8f85db28e64affd263d087db78eb73b2add50543791591129

- select substring(SHA2('This is my secret iv',256),1,16);

413149ee42cfcda5

- trim('palima')

palima

All the mid results are the same. So I have done the conclusion that `openssl_encrypt` and `AES_ENCRYPT` doesn't work the same way.

Do you know how to perform properly the function from PHP `openssl_encrypt` into MySQL? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use php's hash function instead?

Comment: Your encryption is insecure - `IV` **must** be different every time you *encrypt* the data and you *must* deliver that IV to your decrypt method. You're not doing that. Also, mixing two systems for no reason won't do you any good. What would you achieve if you encrypt in PHP and decrypt in MySQL? You even delivered decryption key to the query (insecure because symmetric key is visible),   you might as well decrypt in PHP and deliver that to MySQL.

Comment: @Mjh it's because we're creating a huge amount of new users to our database via MySQL (we are using pdi kettle program) and another client want to get the data with PHP. So you suggest encrypting the password via php function and sending it to MySQL?

Comment: @Eric excuse me, but I didn't understand you. You say that my function in PHP doesn't use the php's hash function? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Guifré, my mistake

Comment: If you are **encrypting** people's passwords, that means you can decrypt them and actually read those. That's not good for you or the customer. Passwords are *hashed* so you don't have a clue what it is but can still verify that users entered the correct password. You went the wrong way about this, take a look at [password_hash](http://www.php.net/password_hash) function.